# MySQL-python installer doesn't find right version of Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

so I'm trying to install MySQL-Python thru the exe found [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5).  only problem is, whenever I open up the exe, it only wants to use a version of Python that was installed when I installed ArcGIS a while back - I need it to use my regular Python path.  This is all I see when I open the installer:
[image: only ArcGIS python path]

The usual way to fix stuff like this is fixing your environment variables, so I've looked at them, but the ArcGIS python install isn't even listed on there - my python path points to the right version of Python, so I don't understand why this installer insists upon the ArcGIS version, even after I've deleted the entire ArcGIS python folder.

I can't change it in the installer - any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installer in your case is looking in the registry so check the registry for the installation path, specifically check:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python
```

and / or

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python
```

The first is for 32 bit python versions that are installed in 64 bit platforms, the 2nd is for 64 bit python.

Here is a screenshot of my registry entry:

[image: python registry entry]

**WARNING**: **Take a backup of your registry if you are going to make a change and tread carefully.**